# Index was outside the bounds of the array. CATCH an error

Tags: c#, asp.net

So my code works fine and everything.  But when nothing is put into the textbox1 and textbox2 and I hit the submit button I receive the error Index was outside the bounds of the array. CATCH an error.

However I tried inputting an else to catch the error and change the label to Cannot Find, instead of the server error but its not working, why is that?

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string CustomerID = TextBox2.Text;
    // 1off


    WebReference.WebServiceTyped ws = new WebReference.WebServiceTyped();
    WebReference.CheckPartStatus PQ = new WebReference.CheckPartStatus();
    string Parts = "";
    string PartNumber = Parts;
    string PriceSum = null;
    long QtySum = 0;

    PartNumber = TextBox1.Text;

    if (PartNumber == TextBox1.Text)
    {

        PQ = ws.CheckPartNumberStatus(PartNumber, CustomerID, "1,6,8,9,112", "", "", "");

        PriceSum = String.Format(PQ.Parts[0].Cost.ToString(), "####.00");

        Label1.Text = PriceSum;
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Cannot Find";
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `PartNumber = TextBox1.Text;

    if (PartNumber == TextBox1.Text)
    {` ... Surely this is senseless. You assign `TextBox1.Text` to `PartNumber` then immeadiately check if they are equal???

Comment: You should be more explicit about what you mean by "it's not working". That said, you'll never get into the `else` clause, because the `if` expression is simply comparing a variable and a property that had just been used to assign to the variable. It's guaranteed they will always be equal.

Comment: easiest thing to do is check for the Textbox value look up how to use the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` function you could save yourself a lot of headaches without having to add `if Conditional` checks inside you main code blocks check if first..or better yet add some message box that error popup if both text boxes length is `= 0` start using the debugger and get away from the good old `Code and Go` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this line:

```
PartNumber = TextBox1.Text;
```

Immediately followed by this:

```
if (PartNumber == TextBox1.Text)
```

Which will always be true given that you just set that value to `PartNumber`.  Therefore, you'll never enter your `else` statement.

What you should do is check to see if `PQ` has anything in it before using it:

```
if (PQ.Parts.Length>0)
{
    PriceSum = String.Format(PQ.Parts[0].Cost.ToString(), "####.00");
    Label1.Text = PriceSum;
}
else
{
  Label1.Text = "Cannot Find";
}
```

This will catch many problems: bad customer id or bad part numbers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when no Text is declared in CustomerId , the CheckPartNumberStatus is failing, try catching the empty inputn like that:

```
string CustomerID = TextBox2.Text;
if(CustomerId == string.Empty){
  //error display
  return;
}
```